# consultar ciertos campos PHP y SQL para pasarlos dentro de una tabla

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo mi select que me arroja lo siguiente:

QUERY SELECT: Mi controlador de php uso "sqlsrv" ya que tengo sqlserver2014

```
$query = "Select [Sucursal],Year([ETA]) Anio,month(ETA) As 'Mes',count(*) AS 'cuenta'
    FROM [TablasTemp].[dbo].[RepCostosFW9]
    where [Facturado] like 'Sin FACTURA%' and year(ETA)=year(GETDATE())
    Group by [Sucursal],Year([ETA]),month(ETA)
    ORDER BY Sucursal";

    $result =sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);

Aqui muestro la informacion el cual trae mi query:

    Sucursal    Anio    Mes numeroDEcuenta
    Air         2019    8   1
    Air         2019    9   5
    CGLLC       2019    6   1
    CGLLC       2019    9   1
    CUSMX       2019    5   1
    Guadal      2019    11  4
    LRTD        2019    11  8
    MEX         2019    1   2

Lo que quiero es en php obtener los datos y llenar mi tabla
```

como por ejemplo: obtener el nombre de mis sucursales, el año y mes de cada una y se muestre en mi tabla

```
    <table>
    <th>datos</th>
    <td><?php echo $row["Sucursal"]?><td>
    </table>
```

Comment: hacen falta datos como: gestor que usas para almacenar tus datos, que driver usas para conectarte (mysqli o pdo), te invito a leer [ask]

Comment: oh disculpa olvido colocar uso sqlsrv

Comment: no se entiende a que tabla quieres pasarlo? recorrerlos por foreach e imprimir en una tabla html o que?

Comment: Imagino que te refieres a convertir los datos que has obtenido de la consulta SQL a una tabla HTML generada en PHP, ¿cierto? En ese caso, ¿la quieres generar en tiempo de ejecución del script PHP o de manera asíncrona mediante XHR (Ajax)? En ambos casos sería de mucha utilidad que compartieras el código PHP que usas para hacer la consulta y obtener los registros.

Comment: Asi es requiero mostrar los datos obtenidos en una tabla html generada en php por edio de un script de php mi codigo lo pondre en mi post.